# Primary menu shortcode name

Tags: menus, shortcode

I have a shortcode that will put a menu where I want it, but it only works on the primary menu.  I don't want to use the shortcode for the primary menu, I would like to create a new menu called shortcodemenu and have the shortcode call it when it is used.

```
function print_menu_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array( 'name' => null, 'class' => null ), $atts));
return wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => $name, 'menu_class' => $class, 'echo' => false ) );
}
add_shortcode('shortcodemenu', 'print_menu_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have everything set. You simply need to call the shortcode:

```
[shortcodemenu menu="slug-of-your-menu"]
```

Remember to use the SLUG of the menu you want to show instead of its name.

Comment: Welcome to Wordpress Stack Exchange! Please note that you **must** disclose your affiliation when linking to a website; for more information, read [How not to be a spammer](/help/promotion).